# What is the difference between eczema and urticaria?

Tags: dermatology, practice-of-medicine, autoimmune-disease, inflammation, allergen-immunotherapy

What is the difference between eczema and urticaria? 
I want to know the pathophysiology and most common causes to understand why they are different !

Comment: I'm thinking the opposite. What do the two have in common? What leads you to ask this question and what research have you done to investigate it?

Comment: I am studying medicine and I saw this 2 cutaneous anomalies so much which lead me to know more and exactly the mechanisms of them !

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. I didn't mean what motivated you to ask the question; I meant what research have you done? What leads you to think these two things are connected? Doing some basic research before asking a question is a requirement here.

Answer (score 6):

### [Eczema](https://www.dermnetnz.org/topics/atopic-dermatitis/) (atopic dermatitis)

> Atopic dermatitis is a chronic, itchy skin condition that is very
>   common in children but may occur at any age. It is also known as
>   eczema and atopic eczema and was formerly known as Besnier prurigo. It
>   is the most common form of dermatitis.

**[Pathophysiology](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/29063428/)**

> The pathophysiology of atopic dermatitis is complex and
>   multifactorial, involving elements of barrier dysfunction, alterations
>   in cell mediated immune responses, IgE mediated hypersensitivity, and
>   environmental factors. Loss of function mutations in filaggrin have
>   been implicated in severe atopic dermatitis due to a potential
>   increase in trans-epidermal water loss, pH alterations, and
>   dehydration. Other genetic changes have also been identified which may
>   alter the skin's barrier function, resulting in an atopic dermatitis
>   phenotype.

The causes of eczema are multifactorial,  it relate to a breakdown in the barrier function of the skin, dehydration and an associated immune response and inflammation. For this reason, [emollients](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/emollients/) and [topical steroids](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/topical-steroids/) are commonly used in its management.

### [Urticaria](https://www.dermnetnz.org/topics/urticaria-an-overview/)

> Urticaria is characterised by weals (hives) or angioedema (swellings,
>   in 10%) or both (in 40%). There are several types of urticaria. The
>   name urticaria is derived from the common European stinging nettle
>   Urtica dioica.

**[Pathophysiology](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/16461989/)**

> Urticaria is dermal edema resulting from vascular dilatation and
>   leakage of fluid into the skin in response to molecules released from
>   mast cells. The major preformed mediator histamine produces a
>   prototypic, short-lived urticaria. However, the clinical spectrum and
>   pattern of lesions indicate that other molecules, including
>   prostaglandins, leukotrienes, cytokines, and chemokines, produced at
>   different times after mast cell activation contribute to the
>   polymorphism of this symptom and the variable evolution of this
>   disease.

The Pathophysiology link goes into some detail about the different forms of urticaria, both immunological (e.g. allergy, infection, vaccination) and non-immunologcial (e.g. aspirin, non-steroidal anti-inflammatory drugs).

The underlying issue is release of inflammatory mediators from [mast cells](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mast_cell). Histamine is one of the most common of these molecules, which is why [antihistamine](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/antihistamines/) drugs are an effective treatment for urticaria.

---

In summary, eczema is localised to the skin, whereas urticaria represents the cutaneous manifestation of a more systemic process.

---

**Sources**:

[dermnetnz.org](https://www.dermnetnz.org)

[Pathophysiology of Eczema](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/29063428/)

[Pathophysiology of Urticaria](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/16461989/)